# Find the "potential" width of a hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently extending the [lavalamp plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/) to work on dropdown menus but I've encountered a small problem. I need to know the `offsetWidth` of an element that is hidden. Now clearly this question makes no sense, rather what I'm looking for is the `offsetWidth` of the element were it not hidden.

Is the solution to show it, grab the width, then hide again? There must be a better way...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to show it (or a clone of it) to allow retrieval of the offsetWidth.

For this measurement step, just make its position absolute and its x or y value a big negative, so it will render but not be visible to the user.

Comment: Here is a blog post on this topic.  One problem this method could encounter is resetting the position back to the original value. Using the swap method works good in this situation. http://bit.ly/6KwGzm

Comment: You don't need to reset it back to it's original position if you're cloning the element. Just remove the clone after you have retrieved its position.

Answer (score 54):

The width of an element that has CSS `visibility: hidden` is measurable. It's only when it's `display: none` that it's not rendered at all. So if it's certain the elements are going to be absolutely-positioned (so they don't cause a layout change when displayed), simply use `css('visibility', 'hidden')` to hide your element instead of `hide()` and you should be OK measuring the width.

Otherwise, yes, show-measure-hide does work.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following function to get the outer width of an element that is **inside a hidden container**.

```
$.fn.getHiddenOffsetWidth = function () {
    // save a reference to a cloned element that can be measured
    var $hiddenElement = $(this).clone().appendTo('body');

    // calculate the width of the clone
    var width = $hiddenElement.outerWidth();

    // remove the clone from the DOM
    $hiddenElement.remove();

    return width;
};
```

You can change `.outerWidth()` to `.offsetWidth()` for your situation.

The function first clones the element, copying it to a place where it will be visible. It then retrieves the offset width and finally removes the clone. The following snippet illustrates a situation where this function would be perfect:

```
<style>
    .container-inner {
        display: none;
    }

    .measure-me {
        width: 120px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-outer">
    <div class="container-inner">
        <div class="measure-me"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please be aware that if there is CSS applied to the element that changes the width of the element that won't be applied if it's a direct descendant of body, then this method won't work. So something like this will mean that the function doesn't work:

```
.container-outer .measure-me {
    width: 100px;
}
```

You'll either need to:

- change the specificity of the CSS selector ie. `.measure-me { width: 100px; }`
- change the `appendTo()` to add the clone to a place where your CSS will also be applied to the clone. Ensure that where ever you do put it, that the element will be visible: `.appendTo('.container-outer')`

Again, this function assumes that the element is only hidden because it's inside a hidden container. If the element itself is `display:none`, you can simply add some code to make the clone visible before you retrieve it's offset width. Something like this:

```
$.fn.getHiddenOffsetWidth = function () {
    var hiddenElement $(this)
        width = 0;

    // make the element measurable
    hiddenElement.show();

    // calculate the width of the element
    width = hiddenElement.outerWidth();

    // hide the element again
    hiddenElement.hide();

    return width;
}
```

This would work in a situation like this:

```
<style>
    .measure-me {
        display: none;
        width: 120px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="measure-me"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, but it won't work with any kind of styling inheritance, or container dictated styling.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer. There are a couple of suggestions in there to get around this but I agree, it's not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. position the element outside the viewport (ex: `left:-10000px`)
2. use `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` instead of `hide()`.

Either way will work as hiding the element but still being able to get the computed width. Be careful with Safari on thi, it's awfully fast and sometimes too fast...

Answer (score 3):

[Actual jQuery plugin](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/)!

**Usage:**

```js
console.log('width without actual: ' + $('#hidden').width());

console.log('width with actual: ' + $('#hidden').actual('width'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.actual/1.0.19/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100px; display: none;">
  <div id="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was ; 
by the time hiding that element, stored its width in its dataset. 
**It only will work for you if you can hide programmatically.**

ie.

**When Hiding ;**

```
var elem = $("selectorOfElement");

elem.dataset.orgWidth = elem.clientWidth;
```

**Later when getting ;**

```
var elem = $("selectorOfElement");

var originalWidthWas = elem.dataset.orgWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the element to be the full width of a parent element another approach is to create a recursive method:

es5:

```
var getWidth;
getWidth = function($el){
  return $el.offsetWidth || getWidth($el.parentElement);
}
var width = getWidth(document.getElementById('the-element'));
```

es6:

```
let getWidth
getWidth = ($el) => $el.offsetWidth || getWidth($el.parentElement)

const width = getWidth(document.getElementById('the-element'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody suggested:

```
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
.shown {
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
}
```

Akward solutions:

- Using `visibility: hidden` is akward because the element still takes up space.
- Using `position: absolute; left: -10000px` is also akward because it may introduce horizontal scrolling if not clipped correctly with `overflow: hidden`.
- Using `.clone().appendTo('body')` is a brittle `// HACK` which will most likely break. Your responsive CSS needs to be scoped correctly for 2 locations in the DOM. Your JS rendering logic needs to be timed correctly for this detour. Please also consider that your server side pre-rendering is often done in Node. :)

Comment: I tried a lot of methods that didn't work in my case or were awkward as you say. A big thank you from me! :)

Answer (score 0):

thats because its hidden via display: none; What ive done in the past is to make a "reciever" div which i use absolute positioning on to get it off the page. Then i load the new element into that, grab the dimensions and then remove it when im done - then remove the reciever when im done.

Another thing you can do is to not use hide(); but to instead set visibility: hidden; display: ; However this means the blank area will be rendered wherever the node is attached.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find working function for hidden element but I realize that CSS is much complex than everyone think. There are a lot of new layout techniques in CSS3 that might not work for all previous answers like flexible box, grid, column or even element inside complex parent element.

**flexibox example**
[image]

I think the only sustainable & simple solution is **real-time rendering**. At that time, browser should give you that *correct element size*.

Sadly, JavaScript does not provide any direct event to notify when element is showed or hidden. However, I create some function based on DOM Attribute Modified API that will execute callback function when visibility of element is changed.

```
$('[selector]').onVisibleChanged(function(e, isVisible)
{
    var realWidth = $('[selector]').width();
    var realHeight = $('[selector]').height();

    // render or adjust something
});
```

For more information, Please visit at my project GitHub.

https://github.com/Soul-Master/visible.event.js

demo: http://jsbin.com/ETiGIre/7

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $hiddenElement = $('#id_of_your_item').clone().css({ left: -10000, top: -10000, position: 'absolute', display: 'inline', visibility: 'visible' }).appendTo('body');
 var width = parseInt($hiddenElement.outerWidth());
 $hiddenElement.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late to this conversation. I am surprised no one has mentioned [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). (Note this only works if the CSS sets a width value)
Grab the element:
`let yourEle = document.getElementById('this-ele-id');`

and use the function:
`getComputedStyle(yourEle).width`

This returns a string so you will have to remove the numbers from the string.
This works even when the element's display style is set to `none`.

Other articles to read about this includes here at [zellwk.com](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/)