# Chrome returns 0 for offsetWidth of custom HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While trying to create an Angular directive that adapts the size of its content to the size of the container, I stumbled over the following issue:

Minimal HTML snippet:

```
<my-tag id="testWidth">
  <div>some text</div>
</my-tag>
```

When reading the width of `my-tag`, I get a result of `0` in Chrome, whereas Firefox returns the correct result. In Chrome, the result is also correct if I replace `my-tag` by `div`.

This is the expression I use to get the width:

```
document.getElementById('testWidth').offsetWidth
```

As far as I know, `my-tag` should be a [valid custom element name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#valid-custom-element-name). Is there anything else that I am doing wrong, or is this simply a bug in Chrome?

Chrome version: 49.0.2623.112 m

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f69b1efq/) for quick testing

I am trying to understand if the behavior of Chrome is correct or if this is a bug.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) says:

> The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout
>   width of an element.

As far as I can tell, it does not say that this only applies to elements with block display. And I also back my understanding by the fact that Firefox returns what I expect.

The same difference in behavior can also be observed for `span` tags, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbz54g9n/).

Comment: I had the same problem on Chrome. Strangely, getBoundingClientRect() has the correct width.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/1841124/1066234

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to style my-tag element with `display: block`

Here's fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lvntyrjy/1/

Comment: Block level elements fill the width of their parents by default, if the desired result is to measure the actual width of the element filled with content, display:inline-block does the trick.

Comment: You have behavior of div element by specifying `display: block`. But good point, if you want to measure element width according it's content, `display: inline-block` or `float: left` on block element will do.

Comment: I have added some more background to the question. Can you point me to any documentation that says that `offsetWidth` is only supposed to work for `block` elements?

Comment: I couldn't find any specification about display style for custom elements. I guess there are no specification for that. Chrome has decided the default display style for custom elements to be `inline` and Firefox has decided that to be `block`. There are other inconsistencies between browsers with default styles and that's why there are CSS resets. One can be found here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and as you can see html5 elements are reseted to `display: block` in this snippet.

Comment: Interestingly in FireFox 88, the default computed display of my custom element is inline, however it still has a valid offsetWidth. So the block display doesn't seem to be a requirement for FireFox to provide an offsetWidth. In Chrome though, Element.getBoundingClientRect() or Element.getClientRects() are alternative options without switching the display mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the width of the content of the custom element like this:

```
document.querySelector('custom-element').shadowRoot.querySelector('#content').offsetWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a design trade-off by Chrome browser in order to optimize for speed and performance. Well, there is always such a trade-off, so you cannot purely blame Chrome. In practical browsing, it is very common to get an element's width and height before it is rendered so that we can plan the overall layout, e.g., estimate how many elements should be shown. An example is a flattened `<select>` that filled the entire panel height (as shown below). In order to determine its `size`, i.e., the number of rows that it should display, we have to divide the height of the parent `<div>` by the `offsetHeight` of its `<option>` (which is always 0 in Chrome).
[image]

So this kind of planned drawing is not possible in Chrome. You have to work around, e.g., by rendering the element first, then get its `offsetHeight`, then redraw the item. Firefox has no such problem, you can always get the `offsetHeight` of its `<option>` at any time.