# How do I determine the height of a ul whose display property is set to none?

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

I am trying to determine the height of a ul (unordered list) whose display property was initially set to none. The property changes to block when a menu icon is clicked. I am trying to replicate jquery's slideToggle in pure javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the "potential" width of a hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841124/find-the-potential-width-of-a-hidden-element)

Answer (score 0):

This works.  It expands the ul captures the height and width and collapses it before the DOM is rendered.

```
<style>
  #myId {
    display: none;
  }
  .display-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
</style>

<button onclick="expandMenu('myId')">Menu Item</button>

<ul id="myId">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>

<script>

  const element = document.getElementById('myId')
  element.style.display = 'block'
  let height = element.clientHeight
  let width = element.clientWidth
  console.log('height', height)
  console.log('width', width)
  element.style.display = 'none'

  function expandMenu(id) {

    const element = document.getElementById(id)
    element.classList.add('display-block')

    let height = element.clientHeight
    let width = element.clientWidth

    console.log('height', height)
    console.log('width', width)

  }

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Since the `<ul>` is set to `display:none;` guess what the value of height and width always is.

Comment: In my situation the ul's display property is set to none in css so obtaining the height with that method will not work.

Comment: I realise that Rob that is why I am asking the question. I read somewhere of doing a clone of the object to obtain the height but I don't know what is involved.

Comment: @user158732 My response is to Flavio, not you.

Comment: Somehow jquery's slidetoggle must be able to determine the height of elements whose display is set to 0 because their function works.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing that out! My bad :)  I've revised to show a strategy that will work if you can capture the ul element inside the onclick event.

Comment: @user158732 I figured it out.  This expands the ul, then captures the height and width and collapses the ul before the DOM is rendered.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for since you haven't provided an example, but try `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('height')`

Comment: Since it's set to `display:none;` the value will always be zero so your answer isn't any help.

Comment: Could you try `element.style.display = 'block'` then get the height then instantly hide it again? I'm not exactly sure what the context is here.